# Как в bash найти строку заканчивающуюся на подстроку и вывести ее?

Tags: linux, строки, bash, подстрока

Eсть строка `string="some text remi other text"`. Нужно извлечь из нее подстроку `some text remi`. Как это можно сделать?

Я смог только ивлечь `"some text "` с помощью команды:`echo ${string%remi*}`

Comment: Думаю не совсем то, что вы ожидаете `echo ${string/remi*/remi}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не совсем понятно сформулированно условие задачи

если я верно понял, то

нужно найти строку в которой присутствует указанная(`remi`) подстрока, а затем вывести первую половину данной строки, то есть, от начала(^) всей строки до найденной подстроки(`remi`) включительно.

пример:

```
строка    -- some text remi other text
подстрока -- remi
результат -- some text remi
```

для этого достаточно использовать grep

```
grep -o ".*remi"
```

пример для одной строки

```
$ echo "some text remi other text" | grep -o ".*remi"
some text remi
```

**p.s.**

ниже в комментариях @ipatev_nn намекнул на то что подстрок в самой строке может быть несколько, по крайней мере это не ограниченно начальными условиями, поэтому для полноты картины попробуем учесть данный вариант. Итак, если подстрок в строке больше чем одна то

учитывать **последнее** вхождение подстроки в строку

```
grep -o ".*remi"
```

учитывать **первое** вхождение подстроки в строку

```
grep -oP "^.*?remi"
```

*вариант @ipatev_nn из комментариев ниже*

от себя добавлю еще вариант с awk

```
awk '/remi/{sub(/remi.*/,"remi");print}'
```

Comment: В случае с "some text remi other text remi" результатом будет вся строка, можно попробовать решить это  `grep -oP "^.*?remi"`

Comment: @ipatev_nn не факт, может нужно наоборот учитывать не первое а последнее вхождение подстроки в строку, в общем нужно чтобы ТС сам уточнил условие чтобы не гадать.

Answer (score 1):

Преобразуйте строку в массив и выводите что хотите:

```
$ string="some text remi other text"
$ array=($string)

$ echo ${array[@]:0:3}
some text remi

$ echo ${array[3]} ${array[0]} ${array[2]} ${array[1]}
other some remi text
```